# The US has banned advanced EUV machines being sold to China, but does it mean that non-China firms cannot use them in China?

Tags: united-states, law, china, technology

Recently the US govt has [banned China firms from acquiring the machines for  14nm process technology and below](https://thediplomat.com/2022/08/lithography-the-achilles-heel-of-chinas-semiconductor-industry/). This legislation specifically targets China firms. However, what stopping non-China firms from working with China firms? Also, for example TSMC has the EUV machines from ASML to produce 7nm and 5nm and potentially 3nm process. But TSMC reportedly has [plants in Shanghai](https://www.globaltimes.cn/page/202204/1259877.shtml), China. Is there any law that specifies they cannot bring those EUV machines made by ASML to mainland China? Whether be it under their own control or leased to another party (the latter beinng a loophole in the law) Sure, its a Taiwanese owned company with plants in mainland China and they have no obligation to deploy those high end manufacturing there, but for a legal perspective, is there anything to say they can't operate such equipment on the mainland?

So what does the law entails? It it a broadly worded just to restrict China Chinese companies from getting hold of advance lithography tech or does it go further in details?

Also if ASML's EUV machines are in Taiwan and if US recognizes one-China policy, then having it in Taiwan wouldn't hold up in a court of law?

Comment: Related: [What political apparatus and rules allow the United States to have leverage against companies when it has several intellectual properties associated?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/74256/26455).

Comment: For the benefit of readers that are not electronic engineers, please could you define the terms you use here, and provide some context. In particular, given this concerns machines used in the semiconductor/chip manufacture industry, it would be useful to use those words somewhere.

Comment: The US cannot prevent Taiwanese companies from doing anything. Best they can do is ask nicely.

Comment: The US can't stop them but that doesn't mean that they can't take actions against anyone who does. There are plenty of examples of the US and other countries taking action against those who do business with people they have sanctions on.

Comment: Did Taiwan ever say it's part of communist China? Utilizing China's cheap labor is one thing, technology transfer is another

Comment: "one China" means something else in US than in China https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/74046/18373

Comment: There are specific US laws that allow courts to treat Taiwan differently/separately https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan_Relations_Act

Comment: @Fizz TRA relates to defence, not technology transfers or jurisdictional use

Comment: "It is the policy of the United States—
                         (1) to preserve and promote extensive, close, and friendly
                      **commercial**, cultural, and other relations between the people of
                      the United States and the people on Taiwan [...]"

Comment: @Fizz so how is that related to a circumvention of Tech restrictions in my described post?

Comment: @Nederealm See Taiwan Relations Act https://www.congress.gov/bill/96th-congress/house-bill/2479/text Section 4. It goes into great detail explaining how for the purpose of American law, Taiwan is treated as a country. The Shanghai Communique and the Joint Communique of the PRC and America of 1982 https://china.usc.edu/joint-communiqu%c3%a9-peoples-republic-china-and-united-states-america-august-17-1982 are both quite clear that that while America acknowledges the PRC's position regarding its claim to Taiwan, America does not go so far as to agree.

Answer (score 0):

This depends from the definition the "China Business"

Following [this source](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/china-business), "China Business" means the Business as operated **in** the Deferred Jurisdiction, including all of the relevant Business Employees, Purchased Assets (so our EUV machines), and Assumed Liabilities. The "Deferred Jurisdiction" is the entity to that the sanctions are applied.

Now what does it mean to be **in** the country? Most logically thinking, this means to be inside the geographical boundaries of the country. I cannot say I am not in the country just because I am on the piece of land within this country, not owned by the local government or local citizens. I cannot say drive a moonshine there or do something else if not permitted by the local laws. Hence if I build a semiconductor plant in this land, it is a semiconductor plant standing **in** the country, so China business. I cannot place the prohibited EUV machines there.